# pandoc lua filter to replace tex macro

Tags: lua, pandoc

I am trying to write a pandoc lua filter to replace the \ce{} command from the latex package mhchem.

This is what I tried with the example of `\ce{NO3-}`, but it doesn't work and renders a blank in the rtf output file:

```lua
return {
  {
    Str = function (elem)
      if elem.text == "\\ce%{%NO3-%}%" then
        return {pandoc.Str "NO3"}
      else
        return elem
      end
    end,
  }
}
```

My pandoc command is:

```sh
pandoc -s myfile.tex --lua-filter myfilter.lua -o myfile.rtf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is how pandoc handles these mhchem snippets: pandoc, by default, drops all LaTeX code which it cannot parse. Example:

```
$ printf 'Nitrate (\\ce{NO3-})' | pandoc --from latex -t native
[Para [Str "Nitrate",Space,Str "()"]]
```

We want to keep those snippets, which we can by using the `raw_tex` extension:

```
$ printf 'Nitrate (\\ce{NO3-})' | pandoc --from latex+raw_tex -t native
[Para [Str "Nitrate",Space,Str "(",RawInline (Format "latex") "\\ce{NO3-}",Str ")"]]
```

Now we have a chance of matching this text.  As we can see, we need to match on RawInline elements instead of Str:

```lua
return {
  {
    RawInline = function (raw)
      local formula = raw.text:match '\\ce{([^ ]+)}'
      if raw.format == 'latex' and formula then
        return pandoc.Str(formula)
      end
    end
  }
}
```

Which will remove the tex command and render the raw code inside.
To match the initial example:

```lua
return {
  {
    RawInline = function (raw)
      local formula = raw.text:match '\\ce{NO3%-}'
      if raw.format == 'latex' and formula then
        return pandoc.Str('NO3')
      end
    end
  }
}
```

Finally, the pandoc command is:

```sh
pandoc --from latex+raw_tex -s myfile.tex --lua-filter myfilter.lua -o myfile.rtf
```

The pattern used for matching wasn't quite correct, as @PaulKulchenko noted. See ["Patterns" section](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1) of the Lua reference manual.

Comment: OK, I am really struggling to figure out what to write after raw.format instead of "...". Is there a way to use gsub on raw?

Comment: @user2165907 the LaTeX content can be accessed via `raw.text`. This is a normal Lua string and can be manipulated with `gsub` and the like. Don't forget that we have to return a pandoc element, so wrap the result with `pandoc.Str`. The code above was updated and contains a working example now.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited your suggestion with a correct regex (we have to match tex commands such as \ce{SO_{4}^{2-}}). Also, this renders the raw content of the initial tex command... Would it be possible to pass it to an unslanted latex math environment so that we avoid to get _^{} symbols in the final rtf? (actually that might have to be another post...)

Comment: Good edit, thanks. I think the follow-up issue warrants an extra question. Have a look at [`pandoc.Math`](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#Math) or [`pandoc.read`](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#read).

Answer (score 1):

You only need to escape special characters *before* them rather than *before and after* and you also need to escape `-`, but don't need to escape `{}`, so `"\\ce%{%NO3-%}%"` should probably be `"\\ce{NO3%-}"`. You can see the list of "magic characters" that need escaping in the [Patterns chapter](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html).