# Pandoc not converting list inside custom environment

Tags: latex, pandoc

I use custom enviroments to produce Theorems, Lemma, Propositions, etc in a LaTex file like this:

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
```

When I use Markdown+pandoc I write:

```
\thm{A theorem.}
```

And I get the desire result.
But when I want to use a list inside it:

```
\thm{A theorem.

1. Item1
2. Item2 }
```

I get:

**1. Theorem 1.** A theorem.

1. Item1 2. Item2

I don't know how to fix this problem. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is possible to include Markdown in an HTML block by using the `markdown_in_html_blocks` extension, the same is not true for LaTeX. There is an [open issue for this](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2453) in the pandoc bug tracker.

The way to solve this is to be very clear in which part of your text is LaTeX:

```
`\thm{`{=latex}A theorem.

1. Item1
2. Item2

`}`{=latex}
```

You could also use a [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) similar to the ones described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56387990/2425163) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57548218/2425163).

Comment: Thanks @tarleb. This is exactly what I was looking for. I will try to make a lua filter for that.